# Change page heading in Joomla based on menu id

Tags: joomla

I am more to Wordpress person compare to Joomla. 
Well i have one problem regarding to Joomla. I am using a non commercial contact form since its has the least features that i want.

However, when i am using this the page heading format for the page is gone since previously i am using the default Joomla's contact form.

By default the page heading is wrapped in H2 tag under the item-page div.

I thought i solve this by modify the third party contact form layout file by putting

```
<div class="item-page"><h2>Contact Us</h2></div>
```

The problem now is i am using this third party component on more than one menu/page. There is another page called Volunteering page. Right now the Volunteering page also shows Contact Us page heading.

I see that each menu has its own ID, like Volunteering id is 517. How can i show different page heading based on the menu ID?

Comment: I solved it! - 
I use `$currentMenuId = JSite::getMenu()->getActive()->id ;`

Comment: If the contact form is written properly it should provide a parameter when you create the menu to set the page title.

Answer (score 0):

You're doing it the hard way. First, as cp21yos mentioned, if the extension is coded properly, it should have the ability to insert it's own page headings per instance. If not, then you can use built in Joomla functionality instead of putting extra code in the extension or template. Simply use a Custom HTML module and assign it to the menu item you want.

Answer (score 0):

You might also read Itemid from the request, even if you use SEF urls, Joomla will make the parameters available so you can use

```
JRequest::getInt('Itemid');
```